# Как добавить команды кнопкам в itemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В первом окне я выбираю какая команда должна быть у моей кнопки, а в открывшемся окне я уже получаю кнопку, но при нажатии ничего не происходит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
У меня есть кнопки в ItemsControl, которые открывают разные окна, в зависимости от команды. Все команды лежат в ObservableCollection. Как мне правильно добавить эти команды к моим кнопкам в VM, чтобы к каждой кнопке была привязана именно ее команда?

Я пытался сделать как-то так, но тогда идет привязка только одной команды.
Совершенно не могу понять как привязать для каждой кнопки свою команду.

```
public RelayCommand AddCommand => calculationDesignModel.InputList[0].AddCommand;
```

CalculationDesignModel

```
    #region Variables
        private string titleOutVariable;
        private string designationOutVariable;
        private string unitOutVariable;
        private string typeOutVariable;

        private string titleInVariable;
        private string designationInVariable;
        private string unitInVariable;
        private string typeInVariable;

        private int quantityInputList;
        private int indexInputItem;

        private string valueInVariable;

        private string imageFileName;


        private string resultFormula;
        private string result;

        private string formula;

        private bool calculateRadioButton;
        private string buttonContent;
        private string titleAddCalculate;


        private ObservableCollection<CalculationDesignModel> inputList = new ObservableCollection<CalculationDesignModel>();
        private RelayCommand addCommand;
        #endregion

        #region Properties
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string TitleOutVariable { get => titleOutVariable; set => titleOutVariable = value; }
        public string DesignationOutVariable { get => designationOutVariable; set => designationOutVariable = value; }
        public string UnitOutVariable { get => unitOutVariable; set => unitOutVariable = value; }
        public string TypeOutVariable { get => typeOutVariable; set => typeOutVariable = value; }
        public string Formula { get => formula; set => formula = value; }
        public string TitleInVariable { get => titleInVariable; set => titleInVariable = value; }
        public string DesignationInVariable { get => designationInVariable; set => designationInVariable = value; }
        public string UnitInVariable { get => unitInVariable; set => unitInVariable = value; }
        public string TypeInVariable { get => typeInVariable; set => typeInVariable = value; }
        public int QuantityInputList { get => quantityInputList; set => quantityInputList = value; }
        public int IndexInputItem { get => indexInputItem; set => indexInputItem = value; }

        public string ValueInVariable
        {
            get => valueInVariable;
            set
            {
                valueInVariable = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ValueInVariable");
            }
        }
        public string ResultFormula { get => resultFormula; set => resultFormula = value; }

        public string ImageFileName { get => imageFileName; set => imageFileName = value; }
        public string Result { get => result; set => result = value; }
        public ObservableCollection<CalculationDesignModel> InputList { get => inputList; set => inputList = value; }
        public bool CalculateRadioButton { get => calculateRadioButton; set => calculateRadioButton = value; }
        public string ButtonContent { get => buttonContent; set => buttonContent = value; }

        public string TitleAddCalculate { get => titleAddCalculate; set => titleAddCalculate = value; }
        public RelayCommand AddCommand
        {
            get => addCommand;
            set
            {
                addCommand = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("AddCommand");
            }
        }
```

```
   <ItemsControl AlternationCount="100" ItemsSource="{Binding InputList}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Tag="{Binding AddCommand, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition  Width="3*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="15 5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignSubheadingTextBlock}" Text="{Binding TitleInVariable, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                                <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}"   VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsEnabled="{Binding CalculateRadioButton}" Content="{Binding ButtonContent}" Command="{Binding Tag,
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                    AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"/>
                                <!--<TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex),RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/> -->
                                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Margin="15" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding ValueInVariable, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Margin="15 5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignSubheadingTextBlock}" Text="{Binding UnitInVariable}"/>

                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
```

Мне нужно добавить команды для этой кнопки.

```
 <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}"   VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsEnabled="{Binding CalculateRadioButton}" Content="{Binding ButtonContent}" Command="{Binding Tag,
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                    AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"/>
```

Прошу, приведите пример правильного присвоения команды для Button в ItemsControl

Comment: *Все команды лежат в ObservableCollection* — напишите точный тип

Comment: ObservableCollection<CalculationDesignModel>

Comment: У вас в `CalculationDesignModel` должно быть свойство `ICommand` и при инициализации (допустим) `CalculationDesignModel` вы инициализируете и нужную команду (прим: `new CalculationDesignModel { Command = new RelayCommand(AddCommand) };`). И так для каждого объекта, который будет у вас в коллекции.

Comment: а в ViewModel что должно тогда уже быть моего окна. Как нужно правильно объявить ICommand?

Comment: Я вам расписал VM, команды в Model быть не должно, это не ее ответственность.

Comment: Дело в том, что моя команда должна же быть привязана к VM, чтобы биндить ее в View. 
А также свои команды я присваиваю в другом классе, а уже потом хочу, чтобы они в другом окне выполнялись

Comment: Мне не понятен ваш вопрос, да и кнопок на ваших скринах я не вижу. Делайте минимальный самодостаточный пример, что бы мы могли его воспроизвести у себя.

Comment: Кнопка это "...". Если я на одном окне выбираю RadioButton - Расчет и в комбобоксе какой-либо расчет, то тогда я в InputList добавляю команду, так как вы описывали выше.
Далее я открываю окно, в котором кнопка или кнопки, которые должны выполнять команды. 
Чтобы выполнить какую-либо команду я могу использовать 
` 
RelayCommand AddCommand => calculationDesignModel.InputList[0].AddCommand;
`
, но это одна команда ко всем кнопкам, что меня и не устраивает. Мне нужно чтобы у каждой кнопки появляющейся в ItemsControl была своя команда